# How do I Create a new page by clicking on my list?

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and would like a syntax view of how you create a new page in connection with a click!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        populateListView(); //First method which fills in my list
        registerClickCallBack(); //Method which reacts when the list is clicked   
    }

    private void registerClickCallBack()
    {
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                nextActivity my = new nextActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateListView()
    {
        String[] myItems = {"I"," II","III","IV" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.da_item,myItems);    

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

How can I create a new xml page when I click on an element in my list? 
How do I write the syntax ?

**Edit:**
I have some extra questions.

Is every new Activity written in a regular class? Why can't I see an onCreate method there then?

Where is the new Activity XML-file stored? In layouts? How do I know which one belong to which whom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start a new activity when an element in your list is clicked like this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

If you want to open another page depending on which item is clicked, you can use the id or position provided by onItemClick();

Then use setContentView in the onCreate() method of your new activity to show the new xml.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

}
```

**EDIT**

You define an activity like this:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity { }
```

You can then Override the onCreate method of your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // What you want to do when the activity is created.

}
```

You add the new XML-file to your layouts folder.
An XML File can be used by multiple activities. In the onCreate Method of your activity, add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);` to open the XML-file with the name activity_next. This can be any name of course.

You might want to read some tutorials.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciate the help, but im a bit confused on some parts.